# What is the theory behind Fourier transform of "bad" (e.g. unbounded) functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis

When I was first introduced to Fourier transform, its core was a formula for it, something like:

$$\tilde f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi i kx}f(x)\text{d}x.\tag1$$

It works nice for good enough functions, for which it converges, for example $\text{sinc}(x)$. But Fourier transform is also used for some more exotic functions, for which $(1)$ diverges, for example $x^2$, or even $\text{sgn}(x)$.

Some sources find Fourier transforms of such functions by regularizations (e.g. multiplying integrand by $\exp(-ax^2)$ and then taking the limit $a\to0$). But this looks like a dirty hack to me.

Obviously, there has to be some more general Fourier theory, than the one involving $(1)$, to handle such functions. What is such a theory? What books present this theory in an accessible way?

Comment: You may be interested in the subject of [Fourier hyperfunctions](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fourier_hyperfunction). Roughly speaking, by considering _analytic_ test functions "a generalization of the Fourier transform is obtained that is wider than the Schwartz theory of tempered distributions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for *tempered distributions*, see for example https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch11.pdf

Briefly, tempered distributions are distributions acting on [Schwarz functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). Using the fact that the usual Fourier transform maps the Schwarz space into itself, this can be used to define the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution (via Plancherel's formula) as

$$ \langle \hat u, \phi \rangle = \langle u, \hat \phi \rangle $$

(other normalizations are possible, and common).